# How can I remove orange-box around the Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d, image

I don't know whether this is a correct question or not, but I played from two days on this problem and still I didn't find a solution.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The save button is enabled whenever we have to specify width,length,height and middleheight of a `Graphics3D`.

`Graphics3D` appears whenever we have clicked on the save button depending upon width, length, height and middleHeight values.

This is my application concept.

For this purpose I wrote a huge amount of code, but I show here only a little bit of the code related to `Graphics3D` and also the sizes of the `Buttons`,`InputFields`and the application-window Size.

```
Dynamic[Pane[
             Manipulate[designSpace, Paneled -> False,AppearanceElements -> None
                       ](*Manipulate is closed here*),
         Scrollbars -> {Automatic, Automatic},AppearanceElements -> None, ImageSize -> {560, 310},Alignment -> {Center, Center}
            ](*Pane is closed here*)
       ](*Dynamic is closed here*)
```

Note:In the code designSpace is `Graphics3D` related code.

The application window size is {580,480}, `Buttons`,`InputFields` sizes {160,60}, pane size {560,310}.

Concept-wise it is working fine but the problem is:

1. `InputFields` and `Buttons` are blinking at the `Graphics3D` rotation time.
2. Some orange box appears around the `InputFields`,`Buttons`and `Graphics3D` whenever we have to double click on the application.
3. If we have clicked on any wall of `Graphics3D`.`createDialog` will appear in that we have to specify the positions, some `Image` overlap on that wall depending upon that specification.

The third point concept is not working. This overlaps with the concepts that I already asked about in my earlier posts, but I still don't get it.

Comment: Could you please try to come up with a minimal working example with buttons and all (we don't need the whole Graphics3D code, a simple box will do)?

Comment: Doesn't the orange box go away when you click outside the image?

Answer (score 4):

Try `Graphics[Circle[]] // Deploy`

Or if you want rotation of 3D graphics as usual but are just annoyed by the selection showing, you could wrap everything in `//Style[#, ShowSelection -> False]&`

Comment: This comes not even close to mimicking the OP's situation. How can you be sure it does any good? If not, I'd post this as a comment.

Comment: @Sjoerd but doesn't Deploy prevent the orange border?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't really understand what the OP meant there, but I now see he means the standard selection box. Deploy will help there, but it's totally unclear (given the question details provided so far) whether it will help wit the two other issues.